# Slack API: How to reply for an attachment action?

Tags: api, chat, attachment, postmessage, slack

I've created an integration with Slack as a WebHook APP. The code is to send a message to a slack channel, using the chat.postMessage method, with some attachment actions, then when the user click the action button, I send him a success message. I'm trying to do something like this:

https://api.slack.com/img/api/message_guidelines/Example_6.gif

The problem is when I try to send the success message. Slack is receiving only the text part of the answer. Here is the code:

```
$message = 'Pre-text message';

$attachments = array(
  array(
    "title" => 'Title message',
    "author_name" => 'My name',
"author_link" => 'https://www.facebook.com/',
"author_icon" => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/picture',
"image_url" => 'https://i.scdn.co/image',
  ),
);

$answer = array(
  'text' => $message,
  'attachments' => json_encode($attachments)
)
```

How can I do to Slack show the answer with the attachment part as shown in the image above? If I comment the text part on $answer, Slack show an error to user ('Oh no, something went wrong. Please try that again.'). Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You never use `json_encode()` on parts of the response, you use it on the entire thing, regardless of what kind of message it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Posting here to help somebody with the same problem. When you posting a message, should json_encode the attachment part, but when posting the attachment action answer, is not necessary. Here is the solution:

```
$message = 'Pre-text message';

$attachments = array(
  array(
    "title" => 'Title message',
    "author_name" => 'My name',
    "author_link" => 'https://www.facebook.com/',
    "author_icon" => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/picture',
    "image_url" => 'https://i.scdn.co/image',
  ),
);

$answer = array(
    'text' => $message,
    'attachments' => $attachments
)
```

Comment: Can you please share the full code, including the attachments block? I'm trying to do the same and can't quite figure out how to link between the button's click and the desired outcome (browsing to a web page)

Comment: Hi @hilaf, I have the answer updated now to include the full code. Sorry the delay on this.

Comment: How can it be implemented in def -

def slack_msg():
    data = {
        "token": "",
        "channel": "",
        "icon_emoji":"",
        "attachments": json.dumps([
            {
             "text":msg,
             "fallback":"msg",
             "color":"",
             "attachment_type":"",
            }
        ]),
        "username": "",
        "mrkdwn": "true",
    }
    response = requests.post("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", data=data, verify=False) 

Will it work if I replace everything after json.dumps with your $attachments value?

Comment: I think you should actually remove the `json.dumps`. I would go for something like:
[slack_msg.py](https://gist.github.com/matheusmaximo/4f9254b8363d9a23f3ae701e730ee870)